# Powerdesigner: Difference between Modification Date and Overall Modification Date

Tags: powerdesigner

Using PD `v15.0.0.2675` in a PDM file.
 I have number of tables where `Modification Date` is different from `Overall Modification Date`.

Trying to determine the difference between the two and what sets each, I have found minimal documentation on Mod Date but nothing on Overall Modification Date. I've changed every property on a test table but can't create an instance where they aren't equal. However, I many tables where they aren't equal.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Overall Modification Date` seems to the max `Modification Date` of the object, and all the objects it contains.